# Manga where main character joins two people on an adventure to try and control his power

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is either reincarnated or summoned (I can't remember) and is extremely powerful, but he can't control his power so it goes off randomly.

He joins two people on an adventure to try and control his power, the party consists of a child and a knight(?).

The whole story is about the shenanigans he gets into because of his power.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Does "op" mean "over-powered?"

Comment: I haven't read it I saw it on a site like about 2 weeks ago but I just remembered a manga with the premise but I can't remember it's name and yes op (over powered)

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/PowerIncontinence/AnimeAndManga

Comment: Nah I couldn't find it on that website

Comment: It's not a not known one so I don't expect to find on any of those list websites

Comment: Do you remember what his power was? Magic? Seduction? Time stopping or reversal?

Comment: Was the manga in black & white or in colour? Also, was the MC a child or an adult, and what colour was their hair?

Comment: I remember it was like explosion magic and some other stuff and it was in black and white and he was like a teenager